# How to search and extract part of string in batch script

Tags: string, batch-file, search, extract

I am pretty new to windows batch scripting and am having trouble to search and extract a portion of a string from a text file and display it out. Some samples data are shown below.

The search is based on student ID, for example: STUD777012

Appreciate if you could help out.

Thank you very much.

### SAMPLE EXPECTED OUTPUT:

STUD777012, return code: 0, Analysis detected no errors

STUD777293, return code: 4, Analysis detected warnings

STUD777086, return code: 8, Analysis detected errors

STUD777099, return code: 0, Analysis detected no errors

### SAMPLE LOG DATA:

```
Compiling STUD777012 to Data Structure 
This is prg version 380.10.20 
This is StudPrg.exe version 6.24 
debug enabled version
StudPrg.exe finished 
prg finished with return code: 0
status:
  Analysis detected no errors

Compiling STUD777293 to Data Structure 
This is prg version 380.10.20 
This is StudPrg.exe version 6.24 
debug enabled version
StudPrg.exe finished
This is StudPrg.exe version 6.24 
debug enabled version
StudPrg.exe finished  
prg finished with return code: 4
status:
  Analysis detected warnings

Compiling STUD777086 to Data Structure 
This is prg version 380.10.20 
This is StudPrg.exe version 6.24 
debug enabled version
StudPrg.exe finished  
This is  StudPrg.exe version 6.24 
debug enabled version
StudPrg.exe finished  
prg finished with return code: 8
status:
  Analysis detected errors
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,6" %%a IN (q25290636.txt) DO (
 IF "%%a"=="Compiling" SET "stud=%%b"
 IF "%%a"=="prg" (
  IF "%%c"=="0" ECHO !stud! return code %%c, Analysis detected no errors
  IF "%%c"=="4" ECHO !stud! return code %%c, Analysis detected warnings
  IF "%%c"=="8" ECHO !stud! return code %%c, Analysis detected errors
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

assuming that it's safe to convert the error-code number to the text (even if it seems superfluous)

I used a file named `q25290636.txt` containing your data for my testing.

You give no data for STUD777099, return code: 0, Analysis detected no errors

---

Revision to isolate one-particular-record.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "target=STUD%~1"
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,6" %%a IN (q25290636.txt) DO (
 IF "%%a"=="Compiling" SET "stud=%%b"
 IF "%%a"=="prg" (
  ECHO !stud!|FINDSTR /L /B "%target%" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   IF "%%c"=="0" ECHO !stud! return code %%c, Analysis detected no errors
   IF "%%c"=="4" ECHO !stud! return code %%c, Analysis detected warnings
   IF "%%c"=="8" ECHO !stud! return code %%c, Analysis detected errors
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

To run for all targets, run with no parameter.

To run for `STUD777293` simply run *thisbatch* 777293

Comment: Hi Magoo, thank you very much for your help. It's working as expected which is GREAT :) I've removed STUD777099 data since its return code is duplicated. I'm not sure if there will be other type of return code, possible to handle any return code not belong to 0, 4 or 8? Thanks.

Comment: It should be fairly obvious how to add extra codes if required. Only you can tell whether it's kosher to infer the Analysis from the return code - but if necessary, the actual text from the "Analysis detected" line could be shown - that's just a little more complicated...

Comment: Hi Magoo, no problem. How can I modify the script to search for STUD777293 (manual entry) and return: STUD777293, return code: 4, Analysis detected warnings ? Planning to add it into my batch script. Thanks.

Comment: Great. If you'd care to click the big tick, that marks the problem solved.